# How do I install dash plugins to search online from the dash in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 22.10

I am on Ubuntu Unity 22.10 Kinetic Kudu. I enabled online searching in settings as you can see here:

[image: settings screenshot]

Here are all the dash plugins that are on my computer:

[image: plugins screenshot]

How do I install the required dash plugins and how do I use them?